Signed Distance Functions into explicit representations?
I am creating a product which would benefit from conversion of 3d implicit surfaces (also called Signed Distance Functions or F-reps) to explicit boundary representations.
I am creating implicit surfaces in my application from constructive solid geometry and I'd wish to convert them into explicit surfaces - explicit being lines, faces, NURBS, and everything in that range.
My surfaces are also quite blocky. NURBS are very uncommon while straight faces are a norm.
Could it be that I would, by means of derivation of lines and faces, or by some kind of mathematics convert largely linear SDFs into faces and NURBS?
Example models attached:
Model view 1
Model view 2
Second model
They are complex shapes but probably survivable for mathematical functions?
Again, they are built with a bunch of
def box(point_to_evaluate: np.ndarray, measurements: np.ndarray, position: np.ndarray):
    vector = np.abs(point_to_evaluate - (position + measurements / 2)) - measurements / 2
    return np.linalg.norm(jnp.maximum(vector, 0.0)) + np.minimum(np.max(vector), 0.0)

and the like functions.
Cheers everyone.

This is an active area of research and there are no simple solutions to this problem. I think state of the art is to convert your implicit surface to STL (or similar) and then semi-manually convert rectangular patches to NURBS patches. Here is a commercial solution: https://support.ntop.com/hc/en-us/articles/7323484481555-How-to-export-geometry-as-a-CAD-part-STEP-or-Parasolid
